# Cos'è un "mezzo vetro"?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Storia di chi fugge e di chi resta* di Elena Ferrante ho letto:

> Enzo fece cenno di sì, ma capii che la preoccupazione per Lila gli aumentava a ogni gradino come aumentava a me, e sentiva la colpa di essersi distratto con quelle chiacchiere. Aprì la porta, disse ad alta voce siamo qua, mi indicò un uscio col **mezzo vetro** smerigliato da cui veniva un chiarore di pochi watt. Bussai leggermente, entrai.

Non capisco bene cos'è un "mezzo vetro". Ho cercato alla voce "vetro" in alcuni dizionari, ma non ho trovato nulla a riguardo. Sapreste spiegarmi qual è il significato?

Comment: Penso si riferisca ai vetri smerigliati che si usa mettere nelle porte i quali lasciano  passare la luce ma non ci si può vedere attraverso. https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR9PJD2UKIEULYnft2QUhZ3nGyhKrV9Ftd4q0k0MkEVNIakkoqt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'uscio col mezzo vetro è una porta dotata di un vetro nella sola metà superiore.
Per avere un'idea di come siano queste porte, si può fare una ricerca di *porta mezzo vetro* su internet.

In particolare nel testo viene detto che il vetro è smerigliato, ovviamente per permettere alla luce di passare e allo stesso tempo evitare gli sguardi indiscreti.

Attraverso questo vetro è possibile vedere che all'interno è accesa la luce, ed avere una idea di quanto questa sia intensa.

Comment: Avevo cercato "mezzo vetro" su Google, ma non "porta mezzo vetro".